# How to run a Batch File at Windows Login?

Tags: windows, batch, login

All the search results out there show about Windows Startup only!! I wish to start a batch file at User Login Session in Windows environment.

Comment: Do you mean on the logon screen, or as they log on

Comment: As they log on. I some times log off my account. It shall run when any person logs into my account or in a guest account.

Comment: Task scheduler then could be an option

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in the Windows Task Scheduler.

Once in the Task Scheduler navigate to the menu and go to

`Action -> Create Task`

In the `General` tab you have to set a name, privileges and configuration options.

In the `Triggers` tab you will have to create a new trigger for `At Logon` for all or a specific user

Finally, you have to create a new action in the `Action` tab. The action should point to your batch file.

Optionally, you can set some more parameters in the `Conditions` and `Settings` tabs.

Comment: I know about task scheduling. But I feel its priority is sometimes overruled. I wish to do it purely in scripts(bat, vba whateva...).  :)